# What are two values in parentheses for in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this code:

```
let n = (this.params.domain, []);
```

Testing it always gives the empty array back.

What is this construction for?

When is `n` something other than `[]`?

Comment: In what context was this code?

Comment: _"When is n something else than [] ?"_ Never. `(this.params.domain, [])` always returns `[]`.

Comment: It will always be `[]`. Not sure why the author wrote that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Unless it was to trigger the property access.

Comment: looks like an approach to unbound this ... it should be a dupe.

Comment: You'll need to ask the author themself to know why they wrote such a horrible thing. Even if they want to trigger the property getter, they could have done so on a separate line.

Comment: Accidentally deleted a function name in a function call `foo(this.params.domain, [])`?